# JavaFX Can't Remove Space at top of Tabs

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx

I've been tweaking the CSS for hours now and I've given up. I can't figure out how to remove the spacing at the top of my tabs. Please help!

[image]

CSS:

```
.tab-pane {
    -fx-tab-min-height: 3em;
    /* 24 */

    -fx-tab-max-height: 3em;
    /* 24 */
}
.tab .tab-label {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-text-fill: #EBEAF0;
}
.tab {
    -fx-background-insets: 0.0;
    -fx-background-radius: 0.0;
    -fx-background-color: #17181B;
}
.tab:selected {
    -fx-background-color: #21477A;
}
.tab:focused {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
}
.tab {
    -fx-padding: 0 30 0 30;
}
.tab-pane *.tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: #17181B;
}
.tab-pane:top *.tab-header-area {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.416667em 0.166667em 0.0em 0.0em;
}
.tab:selected .focus-indicator {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
}
```

Can someone please tell me how to remove that little bit of space at the top of the Settings tab? Thanks!

Comment: I can see `padding` settings, but nothing for `margin`, maybe something there went wrong ?

Comment: The issues is with the default settings of JavaFX. They add spacing to the sides and top by default.

Comment: You may wish to use [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) to debug layouts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me changing the

```
-fx-padding: 0.416667em 0.166667em 0.0em 0.0em;
```

to

```
-fx-padding: 0.0em 0.166667em 0.0em 0.0em;
```

of `.tab-pane:top *.tab-header-area` worked as expected.